# Why restart-computer command takes longer than timeout value when restarting remote computers?

Tags: powershell

I am using following PowerShell command to restart a remote  computer `Restart-Computer -ComputerName Host123 -Force -Wait -Timeout 300`. Even though I specify 5 min timeout it takes 13-15min for timeout to occur.

Can someone please explain why PowerShell won't respect timeout in this case and how can I achieve the correct timeout?

Comment: Is your intention to just restart computer after 5 mins? Or you wanted to achieve something else as well?

Comment: @MuditBahedia This won't restart the computer after 5 mins but it will restart the computer now and wait till it can be reached again before executing the next command. But it should indeed wait  only wait 5 mins  before executing the next stuff and not longer...

Comment: @H.D. did you try `Measure-Command { <# your command #>}` to measure how long it takes exactly?

Comment: @T-Me yes and the timeout is not respected. I run this command as a job (since I am trying to reboot multiple computers) not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: I also noted this very same issue with '-timeout' option. What is it for if it ignores the timeout and waits anyway? @Microsoft ?